# Java Selenium cannot get element

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

i'm using Selenium (java)

the site is : https://www.maersk.com/schedules/pointToPoint

I would like to get the input element "From (city, country/region)" but I can't..

[image]

the input element is :

```
<input part="input" aria-labelledby="label" aria-describedby="hint" data-cy="input" class="input    " type="text" id="destination-input" placeholder="" autocomplete="off" invalid="" aria-invalid="true">
```

I tried with xpath:

```
//*[@id="origin-input"]
```

and full xpath :

```
/html/body/div[3]/main/div/div[1]/form/mc-c-origin-destination//div/mc-c-location-servicemode[1]//div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/input
```

How can I do?
Thank you!

Comment: If the element has `id="destination-input"`, why are you trying `//*[@id="origin-input"]`?

Comment: my mistake.. the first input (From city) has id = origin-input .. I copied/pasted the second input (wrongly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your element is placed in 2 `shadow-root`s, to access it you need to get element via `JavascriptExecutor`.

The shadow root is a document fragment that is attached to the host element and it has a host property that identifies it`s host element. The act of attaching a shadow root is how the element gets its shadow DOM.

So, before getting inner element, you should get host element instead and get it's `shadowRoot` property that would represent root element of `shadowRoot`.

1st host has locator `.origin-destination`

2nd host has locator `#origin`

And only after getting inside 2nd host, you can get your input with locator `#origin-input`.

```java
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
WebElement input = (WebElement) js.executeScript("return document.querySelector('.origin-destination').shadowRoot.querySelector('#origin').shadowRoot.querySelector('#origin-input')");
```

Comment: thanks, if i get a WebElement from javascript (JavascriptExecutor ), then i can interact with the WebElement (input) as if i found the element with xpath?

Comment: Yes, `input.sendKeys("data")`;

Comment: Thanks, but I wasn't the first one... that's very looong story.
More concrete tutorial: http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/accessing-shadow-dom-elements-with-webdriver

Comment: Hi Yaroslavm!
it works! 
WebElement origin_location = (WebElement) js.executeScript("return document.querySelector('.origin-destination').shadowRoot.querySelector('#origin').shadowRoot.querySelector('#origin-input')");
... but when i do origin_location.sendkey("new").. it opens a list and i cannot select an element of that list.. how can i do that?

Comment: infact after sending the key .. the list with the suggested cities disappears immediately

Comment: i get the list with : 
WebElement origin_location_list = (WebElement) js.executeScript("return document.querySelector('.origin-destination').shadowRoot.querySelector('#origin').shadowRoot.querySelector('#origin > div.mc-c-location-servicemode-host--location > div > div > mc-list')");

Comment: Your auto-suggestions is another shadow-root. :) https://monosnap.com/file/pEjK5SxW10QH5giypJ6SYzDOqzZaQf